# Trend Function returning Na values

Tags: r, time-series, na, trend, forecastr

I have used the package `forecast` in R for my time series to obtain the trend values, so i have used firstly the function `decompose` and then `decompose$trend`.

```
Series<-msts(Data, seasonal.periods=c(7,365),start(2014,1))
dec<-decompose(Series,type="additive")
T<-dec$trend
```

The data:

```
73
111
75
180
79
26
26
26
31
38
175
48
38
31
22
25
34
141
40
37
21
28
27
33
100
57
33
32
21
29
48
89
65
52
18
32
32
47
71
82
69
28
28
29
60
35
100
120
83
60
64
108
431
231
97
39
35
43
65
141
91
70
40
35
44
62
97
124
121
44
44
55
87
85
100
176
60
47
50
88
115
127
197
79
61
48
94
119
162
239
99
63
38
101
202
220
33
123
68
91
230
291
231
162
122
76
185
259
228
150
356
201
73
119
443
351
320
168
88
91
123
131
118
164
296
132
82
97
139
21
18
48
126
63
91
130
148
205
273
128
95
112
214
119
183
292
187
155
195
202
213
340
289
29
91
97
196
187
186
153
120
85
115
243
169
192
244
17
86
177
234
161
180
283
143
83
124
241
216
280
19
129
102
161
233
233
272
278
111
151
160
288
259
293
213
117
156
206
293
233
279
267
115
183
134
156
194
178
147
82
90
156
180
193
217
150
103
79
121
138
158
223
147
94
100
134
154
178
189
159
90
71
115
116
176
200
274
104
128
136
150
190
244
181
72
45
75
90
151
191
170
59
66
95
112
151
203
167
63
49
88
97
161
241
262
66
50
81
115
142
237
123
51
48
75
104
113
170
199
56
46
59
114
116
174
211
74
49
67
96
128
139
137
54
47
64
123
101
88
110
79
70
61
92
110
81
72
67
5
41
57
93
59
50
47
57
43
32
99
70
51
30
42
28
42
108
52
47
29
36
50
74
145
75
84
36
47
54
73
203
120
97
37
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
37
38
39
40
42
43
44
46
47
49
50
44
44
44
76
134
179
189
45
34
28
32
45
240
51
29
22
24
29
26
134
67
51
2
34
6
44
87
51
35
30
37
33
43
109
79
59
25
39
25
55
72
87
3
25
41
37
72
81
106
13
88
52
76
94
397
218
69
39
28
4
44
68
98
86
43
35
36
64
71
116
140
34
38
49
80
81
136
212
52
52
54
95
126
178
215
73
47
69
89
138
139
236
122
98
150
112
116
120
124
190
72
107
125
203
358
259
99
128
97
114
123
173
309
150
67
63
115
121
114
135
95
55
92
110
102
160
245
89
75
74
111
113
150
144
99
91
162
139
104
191
258
115
67
115
174
142
160
240
204
114
136
213
233
277
208
118
78
135
147
109
146
111
113
150
137
99
91
162
274
102
80
137
208
155
201
226
36
91
130
238
163
252
163
133
5
146
181
167
283
230
90
87
150
275
193
259
158
105
116
226
242
207
180
176
3
166
1
162
179
229
125
779
86
105
9
20
13
129
91
8
101
147
159
211
146
100
83
124
132
155
216
159
113
97
109
144
158
215
186
5
9
110
122
201
225
219
400
7
86
113
149
218
168
76
51
100
108
178
224
186
54
57
86
101
125
260
200
68
70
79
126
148
254
202
77
60
77
85
145
160
195
48
53
67
94
105
194
217
67
109
68
86
129
145
145
81
72
69
90
216
157
164
87
73
88
94
114
108
99
58
48
60
57
87
89
91
50
37
35
54
87
88
66
60
30
28
32
93
69
73
40
33
40
44
123
82
87
48
33
64
5
13
4
118
58
46
63
78
191
115
107
43
43
9
82
251
96
5
42
50
28
66
27
91
155
55
76
47
60
206
162
78
45
62
64
37
205
56
31
29
31
33
43
141
67
30
24
31
39
37
119
59
36
25
31
33
42
105
81
53
32
45
43
53
96
73
65
22
51
36
101
97
101
109
50
56
62
102
448
225
66
25
33
39
41
75
92
86
41
39
44
57
82
135
152
47
38
56
86
81
147
208
55
64
66
89
142
148
210
81
66
85
173
239
137
265
151
72
78
121
307
380
279
86
62
95
104
187
161
272
71
52
75
108
116
128
227
85
76
67
106
129
150
264
95
51
84
122
118
125
219
94
91
152
78
123
173
303
119
77
75
105
145
148
136
154
82
101
154
133
172
192
4
72
139
163
120
171
328
181
114
136
183
204
286
191
93
93
93
93
93
93
93
93
93
93
93
93
224
233
93
93
102
228
186
239
239
109
90
124
182
214
305
204
96
96
116
210
258
276
241
102
101
157
242
200
244
203
114
148
169
191
175
223
150
90
80
125
143
189
181
169
102
88
113
125
146
175
128
86
79
90
116
169
214
172
77
90
95
124
156
151
143
66
77
99
94
169
190
199
99
124
90
98
160
226
173
66
57
76
73
158
166
160
43
51
88
101
120
221
178
51
65
67
80
134
210
170
52
52
79
98
104
201
153
51
50
60
88
113
142
182
52
42
63
85
85
117
94
57
53
63
74
103
129
102
70
73
75
87
128
122
90
32
34
30
44
87
47
76
36
26
25
56
59
65
40
26
41
23
51
83
48
46
43
36
34
45
131
45
79
26
41
68
54
150
85
88
39
32
60
73
217
94
98
38
36
49
95
263
69
55
46
75
35
66
105
80
19
104
106
81
62
46
```

My problem is that the vector T that contain the trend values contains Na values. How this result can be  interpreted?

Comment: data and code please.

Comment: I have added the code and data